# ASP, CSS and C# - Fixing Gridview Headers for Scrolling

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Work on the website is going well and I am adding the more fancy features. I noticed their gridviews were incredibly long vertically so I started adding a scrollbar to sort it out. Problem is that the header disappears. There are a few solutions online but all of the ones I have found either do not solve the problem or use JavaScript.

I am willing to use JavaScript if it comes to it, **but ideally would only like to use ASP, C# and CSS** (I am trying to keep the code as close to their original layout and code design as possible). Is this possible or is JavaScript the only way to go? I have provided the tags for ASP below

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 800px; overflow: scroll">
<asp:GridView ID="grdInventory" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="FixedHeader" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" onrowcommand="grdInventory_RowCommand" >
    <RowStyle CssClass="normrow" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="oddrow" />
    <Columns>
        ...Data...etc...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView></div>
```

And the CSS current for the FixedHeader style

```
.FixedHeader 
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Any help would be widely appreciated!

Comment: Your question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990435/fixing-gridview-header-while-scrolling?rq=1

Comment: That answer uses JavaScript. As mentioned I am trying not to use Javascript